# How to Match Records from two tables once

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp

[This is the Match Table I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwPzw.png)
I have a problem i am trying to resolve. Kindly help. Thanks in Advance.

**Scenario:** There are three tables in a database. Let's say tblA, tblB and tblC. It's for a service swap kind of scenario. So, tblA contains records of people who request for a service and tblB contains records of those who offer their services. So, tblB is supposed to be matched with someone requesting the same service at the same available time and put the match records into tblC.

**What I have Done/Tried:** I have been able to create a query for a match to occur between both tables which is good progress. But this leads me to a major problem.

**The Problem:** Problem is based on what i've done, the query matches one person requesting to more than one person offering. I want it to be once it matches a record in tblA to someone in tblB and put it in tblC, it should delete immediately so that it doesn't match those records to other people.

**Example code:**

```
    $match = "SELECT * FROM tblmatch";
    $Resmatch = mysql_query($match, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_match = mysql_fetch_assoc($Resmatch);
    $mat_offuemail = $row_match['useremail'];
    $mat_offustype = $row_match['stype'];
    $mat_offtrange = $row_match['trange'];

    if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "request-form")) {
      $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO tblrequest (orderid, useremail, catname, rdate, stype, trange, rdesc, rloc) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['uorder'], "text"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['uemail'], "text"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['rcat'], "text"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['date'], "text"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['serv'], "text"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['trange'], "text"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['rdesc'], "text"),
                           GetSQLValueString($_POST['rloc'], "text"));

      If ($_POST['uemail'] == $mat_offuemail AND $_POST['serv'] == $mat_offustype AND $_POST['trange'] == $mat_offtrange){
        echo "Match Done Previously";
        }
      else{
        $inmatch = "INSERT INTO tblmatch (useremail, userorder, stype, uemail, uorder, trange)
SELECT tbloffer.useremail, tbloffer.orderid, tbloffer.stype, tblrequest.useremail, tblrequest.orderid, tbloffer.trange
FROM tbloffer
INNER JOIN tblrequest
ON tbloffer.stype = tblrequest.stype
AND tbloffer.trange = tblrequest.trange
WHERE tbloffer.useremail != tblrequest.useremail
AND tbloffer.catname != tblrequest.catname
ORDER BY tbloffer.useremail
LIMIT 1";
        }

      mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
      $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
      $Result2 = mysql_query($inmatch, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());

      $insertGoTo = "match.php";
      if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
        $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
        $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
      }
      header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
    }
```

Comment: two comments
a) It would be better to use `mysqli`. `mysql` is outdated.
b) would it not be better to make a view that containts the matching rows, instead of inserting them in to a new table?

Comment: would be helpful if you could add the table def for table A and table B and how they are matched.

Comment: What about adding a new boolean column "Matched"? so you don't have to mess too much with the logic behind tables, they are still offered services afterall, already matched, but still services.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken I am still learning but will migrate soon.  Please can you give an example about creating the view? I will try the Limit 1 you initially suggested an get back to you.  Thank you very much

Comment: @Jacopo I'm not entirely sure what you mean.  Can you explain further?

Comment: @ogo I added an example for the view stmnt. You can also use phpadmin to create it, like you would create a table

Comment: Thank you very much @ErikKalkoken The edited code you gave me works. However, it only matches one person to another and ignores the rest of the table. I presume that's because of the LIMIT 1. I tried doing a LOOP so it checks for other matches but it's not working. Would be grateful if you can help with that.

Comment: `LOOP
   SELECT INTO useremail, uemail  tbloffer.useremail, tblrequest.useremail FROM tblmatch LIMIT 1;
   EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
   RETURN NEXT;

   DELETE FROM tblmatch                              
   WHERE  tbloffer.useremail IN (useremail, uemail) OR 
          tblrequest.useremail IN (useremail, uemail);
END LOOP;
LIMIT 1;`

Comment: You are right, my solution is incomplete. Will take a look at it again tomorrow and come back to you.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken I just used your updated query which works fine but then it takes the email of one person and pairs it to everyone in the request table looking for that service. I updated my question by adding a screenshot if you can see what i'm trying to achieve. Like once someone from offer has been matched to someone in request, those two shouldn't be paired again to anyone except its for a different service or the same service but at a different time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to match with only one offer we can use a sub-query and the `GROUP BY` clause. I am assuming that `orderid` is unique and can be used as primary key to select only one matching offer if they are more than one. With the `MIN` function on the orderid I am always picking the one with smallest ID number, but any other aggregate function will work just as well (e.g. `MAX`).

Here is the complete SELECT stmnt:

```
SELECT tbloffer.useremail, tbloffer.orderid, tbloffer.stype, tblrequest.useremail, tblrequest.orderid, tbloffer.trange
FROM tbloffer
JOIN tblrequest
ON tbloffer.stype = tblrequest.stype
AND tbloffer.trange = tblrequest.trange
WHERE tbloffer.useremail != tblrequest.useremail
AND tbloffer.catname != tblrequest.catname
AND tbloffer.orderid IN (
    SELECT min(orderid)
    FROM tbloffer
    GROUP BY stype, trange
)
```

Again I would suggest to evaluate if you could use a view instead of inserting matching rows by PHP script. A view can be created easily based on the above SQL statement and work as substitute for your script.

Comment: @ogo Thanks for your feedback. I have now updated my answer with a better solution. This time I also tested it with a sample database based on your script to ensure it works.